# Writing SQL command to update a password in a part of a column

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to write an sql command that enters a password inside a string.

The database entry that I need changed is in the `users` table `preferences` column and it looks like this:
`a:2:{s:11:"client_hash";s:16:"hashedpwdhere";i:0;b:0;}` or

`a:1:{s:4:"skin";s:5:"larry";s:11:"client_hash";s:16:"hashedpwdhere";}`

**All I need is to replace the "hashedpwdhere" with the new hashed password.** That is always after s:16: no matter how many other things are in there.

Currently my SQL command looks like this:

```
UPDATE users SET preferences=ENCRYPT(%p,CONCAT(_utf8\'$5$\',RIGHT(MD5(RAND()),8),_utf8\'$\')) WHERE username=%u LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately this erases everything in the preferences column and **I have no clue how to write this to only insert it into the quotes after s:16:**

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above SQL is very product specific.

Comment: to be honest, no clue - this is on a hosting solution I purchased - on the 20i hosting platform if that makes a difference

Comment: The syntax suggests MySQL.  Run `select version();`

Comment: If it's MySQL 8+, you could use basic string functions or [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).  For example something [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=799af57b19cb7a5b42c84332ff94d4f2) might work.  **Always make a backup first, in case something goes wrong you can restore the backup**